# PHP exec and mediainfo

Tags: php, exec, mediainfo

I have a problem with my php script and mediainfo.
I run xampp, i set the permission of my working folder to 777,but if i try to use:

```
exec("mediainfo /path/of/the/file/video.avi > /path/of/the/output/report.txt")
```

or

```
    exec("mediainfo --logfile=path /path/of/the/file/video.avi")
```

it doesn't work.
the same command in the terminal works fine.
Any advice?

Regards

Comment: Do you get any error message? Exec() might be switched off in your server settings.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.
No i don't get any error message.
Exec is on, if i try with other tool or exec simple cli command it works fine

Comment: Hi. Did you try escaping the `"`?

Comment: can you show me how?

Comment: basically that means that you need to tell php to let the special chars pass like this  `exec(\"mediainfo`  - the `backslash` does the trick. There is a lot of documentation online about all the various ways and tricks to do that.

Comment: i try this way but still doesn't work